# VBScript Dictionary Error

Tags: dictionary, vbscript

I'm stuck working on an old project created with classic ASP (VBScript).

I've found the dictionary collection type which seems to be what I need. However, it keeps telling me "This key is already associated with an element of this collection." when I try to load it from a database recordset.

Here is the code.

```
set objRS = objDBConn.Execute("SELECT AreaAbbrev, Area FROM tblArea WHERE CompanyID = 15")
Set areaDict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
areaDict.CompareMode=vbTextCompare

WHILE NOT objRS.EOF
    Response.Write(objRS("AreaAbbrev") & " ::: " & objRS("Area") & "<br />")
    areaDict.add objRS("AreaAbbrev"), objRS("Area")
    objRS.movenext
WEND
```

This is the output:

```
00K ::: Kellogg
00G ::: Girdler

Microsoft VBScript runtime  error '800a01c9' 

This key is already associated with an element of this collection
```

As you can see, "00G" is not the same as "00K". Can anyone tell me why this may be giving me this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After some further research, I found adding .Value in this line fixed the issue:

```
areaDict.add objRS("AreaAbbrev").Value, objRS("Area").Value
```